# I am not able to use (page) and (getSortByToggleProps) in React table in typescript file

Tags: reactjs

I want to include pagination and sorting in react table in typescript but got error in (page) and (column.getSortByToggleProps()). Same code working in java-script

Comment: Please provide more details about which react libraries in use

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-paper-1nc6p?file=/src/App.js                                       We want same functionality but in .tsx extension

Comment: You should give details about the error and your code (in Typescript)